# Accepting an offer before getting feedback from other interviews

Tags: interviewing, job-offer

I'm in a situation where I have completed the interviewing process with three different companies and have received no offers, nor have I been rejected. I greatly prefer one of those companies over the two others. I also have a pretty good idea of what the offers would look like for all three companies.

The company I prefer the most just contacted me to say that I would be getting an offer letter soon. Knowing that I will accept that offer with 99% certainty, when I do, should I not tell the other companies just to see if they had selected me and what their offers would look like?

Part of me thinks that not telling them would be wasting their time because they have to spend time deciding if they're taking me and possibly writing an offer letter. On the other hand, if I tell them that I accepted an offer somewhere else, I'll never get the feedback from my interviews with them... Having gone through the interviewing process, I would like to know if I did good on those interviews and if I would have made it, even if I have no intention of accepting the potential offers.

Comment: " The company I prefer the most just contacted me ". Accept the offer and don't waste anytime on other companies you don't prefer to work with

Comment: @Jon that's terrible advice. What if the offer comes in at a much reduced salary? Or something else happens which makes that offer fall through. He has been told he will get an offer. It's only when you have the offer in front of you in writing and you decide to accept is when you tell the other companies.

Comment: Heh, there are lots of posts on here about accepting offers and whether or not to tell other companies/recruiters, etc. that you have accepted these offers.

Comment: *should I not tell the other companies* - No, don't tell the other companies. If they contact you with an offer, you are free to refuse with the reason "I have already accepted a contract elsewhere" and thank them for their time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should I ask company Y to extend the deadline for their offer when I'm waiting to hear from company X?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/57904/should-i-ask-company-y-to-extend-the-deadline-for-their-offer-when-im-waiting-t)

Comment: @gnat This is not the same in any way. They are talking about being made an offer and asking if they should then tell the other companies an offer has been made to see if they would also make an offer.

Comment: If you receive an offer from another company, and let them know that you got a better offer elsewhere, this may actually be leverage for you. You don't need to be so specific as to tell them that you have another job. What if they counter-offered more?

Answer (score 11):

Don't tell them anything until you **HAVE** a written contract with the company you want to work with.

Even if the company you like, have been in contact with you and said that you will be getting an offer, you should wait until the WHOLE process is done. A lot of things can change, and it's better to keep as many doors open as you can while there is an uncertainty.

When you do receive an offer and written a contract I would suggest to contact the other companies and thank them for their time. This shows a good ending and also that you don't want to use their time in vain.

Comment: I agree here. Yes the other companies may feel their time is wasted, but people have multiple interviews when looking for a job, it's just a fact of life.

Answer (score 0):

This dream job may not feel so dreamy in 6 months. Knowing you have an offer and how much could be valuable. Extending the offer (or not) is not a lot a of work for them. Just decline when you get the offer.

Comment: You should decline when you have accepted another firm offer. If a company makes an offer and your reply is "I accepted another company two weeks ago", they will feel justifiably annoyed, which will not improve your chances if you ever need to apply to them again.

Comment: @DJClayworth I can see your point.